# MYSQL - How to query database by time

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have say 12 results in a database with columns called

```
thread

message

time_posted
```

there are 12 results and they all have the same `thread` witch is 1002.

I'm trying to get all results coming after `time_posted` `"2013-03-19 17:36:08"`.
There are at least 4 entries either side so I should be getting 4 entries that come after this time.

So far out of everything I have tried, I have either received an empty array or I got everything except from the row that has `2013-03-19 17:36:08` as a timestamp.

Here is what I have tried:

```
    public function get_messages($thread){

        $time = '2013-03-19 17:36:08';

        $statement = $this->database->prepare("SELECT * FROM chat WHERE thread = ? AND time_posted > '$time'");

        $statement->bindParam(1, $thread);

        $statement->execute();

        $this->result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return $this->result;

    }
```

I have tried it with both < AND >

Thanks in advance for any help.

All the best.

Connor

Comment: Are those fields defined as `DATETIME`/`TIMESTAMP` in MySQL? If they're `VARCHAR` or another data type, this won't work.

Comment: The time_posted are TIMESTAMP sorry

Comment: what happens when you run your sql in your db shell? Are there any results?

Comment: yes either nothing or everything but the row with the time i stated

Comment: please give us a *real* excerpt from some rows of your table `chat`

Comment: i have added a screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    $time = '2013-03-19 17:36:08';

    $statement = $this->database->prepare("SELECT * FROM chat WHERE thread = ? AND time_posted >= STR_TO_DATE(?, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')");

    $statement->bindParam(1, $thread);
    $statement->bindParam(2, $time );

    $statement->execute();
```

Comment: returns nothing for me i will take a screenshot of my db now

Comment: @ConnorMiles Sorry, It is timestamp, not unixtimestamp! See updated answer.

Comment: no that didnt work if i changed the > to < then it outputs everything but the row with the time_posted as 2013-03-19 17:36:08

Comment: that update only outputs the one with the time_posted set as the time

Comment: @ConnorMiles I think you haven't data in your table with `time_posted` greater than `2013-03-19 17:36:08` for given `thread`.